# Demonstrating Neural network using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to demonstrate a code I prepared for a basic neural network that predicts a variable from the other input parameters. I try to call for the nn$result.matrix and plot the nn I have been using, but I am unable to do so getting an error that nn.results not found.

` server.R
output$plot <- renderPlot({
#inputs leaving for now
req(input$file1)
inFile <- input$file1

```
    # creating DF and omitting NA
    DataSTP1 <- read.csv("/Users/mass/Desktop/Project/STP1.csv" , stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings = c(NA,"NA", " NA", "-", "NT")) 
    DataSTP1_om <- na.omit(DataSTP1)
    
    #Creating NN
    
    BOD_ANN <- data.frame(BODi = DataSTP1_om$BOD_i, BODo = DataSTP1_om$BOD_o, CODi = DataSTP1_om$COD_i, CODo = DataSTP1_om$COD_o, dis = DataSTP1_om$inflowMLD, temperature = DataSTP1_om$temperature, pHi = DataSTP1_om$pH_i)
    
    #normalization
    BOD_ANNpre <- preProcess(BOD_ANN, method=c("range"))
    BOD_ANNnorm <- predict(BOD_ANNpre, BOD_ANN)
    
    #neuralnet
    
    nn <- neuralnet(CODo ~ BODi + dis + temperature + pHi + CODi, data=BOD_ANNnorm, hidden=c(5,2), linear.output=T, threshold=0.01)
    nn$result.matrix 
   plot(nn)        
    
})`
```

Please can someone guide me on this issue as the same issues prevail for other functions I am trying to demonstrate?

Comment: You are not assigning `nn` to anything.  Moreover the `neuralnet` function returns a list.  So you should probably assign `nn` to the proper list element.

Comment: My bad there was a Typo, but still I am not able to get the plot output. Usually in static program I would plot the current Neural net and get output. But in R Shiny I am unable to get one